# ANTLR4 Javascript parser RegExp and division operator conflict

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, antlr4

I am writing a JS parser using antlr4. I am basically using the grammar file posted on Antlr's grammar repository (ECMAScript.g4) as the basis.

The grammar defines the regex rule as below, which in itself is not a problem.

`RegularExpressionLiteral:
    '/' RegularExpressionBody '/' RegularExpressionFlags
;`

However, the parser thinks an expression code like this a regex.

`var x = a / b + c / d;`

I wonder if there is a easy fix for this conflict. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't include all the code from the grammar. Be sure to include all the code inside the `@member` blocks: they are responsible for determining if an `/` should be considered a division operator, or a regex delimiter.

When I run the following test class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ECMAScriptLexer lexer = new ECMAScriptLexer(new ANTLRInputStream("var x = a / b + c / d;"));
        ECMAScriptParser parser = new ECMAScriptParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        ECMAScriptParser.ProgramContext ctx = parser.program();
        new TreeViewer(Arrays.asList(ECMAScriptParser.ruleNames), ctx).open();
    }
}
```

The following screen is shown:

[image]

Comment: Wow, you are one of the contributors of the grammar. I thank you for your comment. Well, ok, I removed the java code from @memeber section because my target language was Javascript. I totally forgot about that I did! I needed a Javascript parser that ran in Javascript environment. I am going to rewrite the code in JS. Thank you Bart.